# Who today are the most eminent Jewish religious leaders in America?

Tags: daas-torah

I would like to know which gedolim are considered to be our foremost authorities on halacah and daas torah and what organizations they represent. Who succeded R' Moshe Fienstien -for example?

Comment: I think the bit about what organizations they represent or yeshivot they are head of credentials etc. are sufficient to allow  vindication of some opinions. By stating these things one can draw their own conclusions. I merely asked so I can seek what stances they hold and what books they authored so I can understand how frum American Jewry is shaped from an arbitrary point of view.

Comment: The question as worded looks like it's asking for opinions. Possibly better worded questions could be who is asked most _sh'elos_ nowadays by other rabbis, who leads the most populous _y'shivos_, who leads the most populous hasidic sects, what national chief rabbis exist, etc. Many of those types of questions, though, are probably answered by referring to a list on Wikipedia or elsewhere online, so, if you want to know the answer, I suggest you do a little research first. (And even then the question might be too localized to this point in time.)

Comment: @msh210 Wikipedia is great -I would like to know from other Jews what they might add. Wikipedia is opinion based and not always complete as you well know. Information in that context is biographical. Just an observation, I see rather than community and sect leaders I see Rosh yeshivot as leaders. To me that is very telling.

Comment: @seekingclarity We are more opinion based than Wikipedia.